# Can´t output correctly pushed content into array on node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, api, express

)

Im working on a node.js express custom API project.
Currently I´m getting a problem when trying to push data...

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = function(config, steamClient, csgo, database, teamspeakClient, router) {
var async = require('async'),
apicache = require('apicache'),
cache = apicache.middleware,
mysql = require('mysql');

async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        router.get('/CsgoUser/requestPlayersProfile/v1/:steamids', function(req, res) {
            var steamids = req.params.steamids.split(',');
            var csgo_data = [];
            steamClient.getPersonas(steamids, function(resp) {
                Object.keys(resp).forEach(function (steamid){
                    if (!steamClient.myFriends.hasOwnProperty(steamid)) {
                        if (resp[steamid].game_played_app_id == 730) {
                            csgo.requestPlayersProfile(steamid, function(result) {
                                console.log(result);
                                csgo_data.push(csgo_data, {steamid: steamid, response: result});

                            });
                        }else{
                            csgo_data.push({steamid: steamid, response: steamid + " is not playing csgo"});
                        }                   
                    }else{
                        csgo_data.push({steamid: steamid, response: steamid + " Is not bot´s friend..."});
                    }
                });
                res.json({ success: true, code: 200, response: csgo_data });
            });


        });

    }
    ])};
```

And here is the  result:

> {"success":true,"code":200,"response":[{"steamid":"76561198013250658","response":"76561198013250658 Is not bot´s friend..."},{"steamid":"76561198263874163","response":"76561198263874163 Is not bot´s friend..."},{"steamid":"76561198156967342","response":"76561198156967342 Is not bot´s friend..."}]}

The problem comes when calling

```
csgo.requestPlayersProfile(steamid, function(result) {
console.log(result);
csgo_data.push(csgo_data, {steamid: steamid, response: result});});
```

The console.log´s output data (ex: {"ID":"hello"}) is displayed correctly on terminal, but it isnt pushed to the csgo_data array...

Please try to give me a explication :-)

Comment: are you getting an error? `TypeError: second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an array` ... why the heck are you doing `csgo_data.push.apply(csgo_data, {steamid: steamid, response: result});` ... rather than `csgo_data.push({steamid: steamid, response: result});`

Comment: @JaromandaX No, Im not getting any error.

Comment: It was just for testing xd.. I have tried also csgo_data.push method.

Comment: @JaromandaX any idea abot what is the problem?

Comment: You should get an error with the code you **posted** what makes you think the push failed?  Log the array after the push. Bet it's there

Comment: if `csgo.requestPlayersProfile` is asynchronous, the `push()` commands inside the callback will be called **after** `res.json()`

Comment: @ChrisG Can you provide me a short code of how shoul it be if csgo.requestPlayersProfile is asynchronous...?

Comment: Can't see where you are trying to read the array. So it's probably an asynchronous issue. I.e. you don't know how asynchrony works

Comment: I use express to read the array... res.json()

Comment: @ChrisG You are right, if i call `csgo_data ` after `res.json` the `requestPlayersProfile` data  is displayed correctly. But how can I get all data in one response?

Answer (score 1):

As for me to avoid such type of problem try to rewrite `forEach(..)` on Promises. Like this:

```
steamClient.getPersonas(steamids, function(resp) {
            Promise.all(Object.keys(resp).map(
              (steamid)=>new Promise((resolve)=>{
                  if (!steamClient.myFriends.hasOwnProperty(steamid)) {
                      if (resp[steamid].game_played_app_id == 730) {
                            csgo.requestPlayersProfile(steamid, (result)=> {
                              console.log(result);
                              resolve({steamid: steamid, response: result});
                            });
                      }else{
                          resolve({steamid: steamid, response: steamid + " is not playing csgo"});
                      }                   
                  }else{
                      resolve({steamid: steamid, response: steamid + " Is not bot´s friend..."});
                  }
                })
             )  
           ).then((csgo_data)=>
            res.json({ success: true, code: 200, response: csgo_data })
           );
});
```

Comment: There is still a problem with this... if there are more than 1 calls to the csgo.requestPlayersProfile function, anithing hapens...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my Promisified version:

```
// build Promise from steamid
function getData(steamid) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var data = {
      steamid: steamid,
      response: steamid + " Is not bot's friend..."
    };
    if (!steamClient.myFriends.hasOwnProperty(steamid)) resolve(data);
    else if (resp[steamid].game_played_app_id != 730) {
      data.response = steamid + " is not playing csgo";
      resolve(data);
    } else {
      csgo.requestPlayersProfile(steamid, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        data.response = result;
        resolve(data);
      });
    }
  });
}

// build array of promises and pass to Promise.all()
Promise.all(Object.keys(resp).map(steamid => getData(steamid)))
  .then(data => {
    res.json({
      success: true,
      code: 200,
      response: csgo_data
    });
  });
```

Comment: There is still a problem with this... if there are more than 1 calls to the csgo.requestPlayersProfile function, anithing hapens...

Comment: @Alex Are you saying that you see multiple console outputs but the response isn't sent?

Comment: I'm saying that if there are more than 1 players playing csgo at the same time, only the first result is going to be showed. The first array items are showed correctly (steamid) but the second item (csgo data) is repeated in each array. Maybe is just and error...

Comment: I need another way (system)  to make this done... any ideas?

Comment: @Alex You need to be more specific. What exactly are you getting in the console? What exactly is the shape of the JSON sent back to the browser? I'm not seeing two different arrays in the code, just one. Ideally, put your code on github so I don't have to build my own version just to find some small error.